# Configure maven-compiler-plugin so it works both with JDK-8 and JDK-12 (in Spring Boot project)

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, build, maven-compiler-plugin

Is it possible to configure `maven-compiler-plugin` so it works **both** with JDK 8 **and** JDK 12? I am not sure if it is relevant, but it is a Spring Boot project.

**1.** The configuration

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <release>8</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

is compilable under JDK-12, but under JDK-8 fails:

```xml
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project xxxx: 
Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release
```

**2.** The configuration

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

which misses the `<release>8</release>` parameter is compilable under JDK-8, but under JDK-12 fails:

```xml
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project xxxx:
Fatal error compiling: CompilerException: NullPointerException
```

All the possible internet sources I found advice to use the `<release>8</release>` parameter to be able to avoid the error under JDK-12, but this disables the compilability under JDK-8.

Our source and target compatibility is Java 8, and we need to **build the code with the good old plain `mvn clean install`** (without providing a profile!) on the developers' machines with JDK-12, but also on Jenkins, where we still have to keep JDK-8, and we also have some conservative developers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first you should define the maven-compiler-plugin within the pluginManagement like this:

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
      <...>
    ...
```

and furthermore using profile which are automatically activated which looks like this:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jkd-12-compile</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>12</jdk>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <release>8</release>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-8-compile</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>[,8]</jdk>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

One not usually a `mvn clean install` is not needed. You usually only need `mvn clean verify`...

Comment: Finally, it works with `<jdk>(,9)</jdk>` and `<jdk>[9,)</jdk>`. Because `<jdk>[,8]</jdk>` has problem with versions like `8.0.152` or so... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Btw, can you explain **why** all this is needed? I don't mean the profiles, these are clear, but why I cannot use just one single configuration for all the JDKs. I tried a single POM config with the plain Java command-line "Hello world" and this works the same under all the JDKs. Is it because of something in Spring Boot?

Comment: This will be not so easy because of NDA. I will try to extract an anonymized MCVE when I have time.

Answer (score 2):

A tad simpler solution relies on using the properties rather than the explicit configuration entries. It won't complain for anything that it doesn't support.

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>jdk9+</id>
    <activation>
      <jdk>[9,)</jdk>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: This is nice. You could just add the profile that is meant to be active when JDK 8 is detected to have fully functional profiles section that I think would make your answer look even better.

Comment: @Paulo `maven.compiler.target` and `maven.compiler.source` may stay in the main `properties` section as they will be ignored by 9+

Comment: Great! Now that you've put the properties along with the profile, this solution is definitely nicer. Thanks!

Comment: @greut - how do I find out exactly which version to set in the properties tag ? I want to use Java 10. Should I set version as 10  or 1.10 ?

Comment: @MasterJoe2 I'd say 10, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/version-5.0.html